# using OneSignal Api in ionic 4 project

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, ionic4, onesignal

I'm trying to create push notification using post request from `ionic 4` using `one signal`

here is how I send the POST request:

```
    async presentAlertMultipleButtons() {
        const alert = await this.alertController.create({
            header: 'Confirm',
            subHeader: 'Your dress is added',
            message: 'Admin team will review the dress and post it as soon as possible.',
            buttons: ['Ok'],
            mode: 'ios'
        });

        await alert.present();
        const post_data = {
            'app_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'contents': {
                'en': 'new dress added to fostania'
            },
            'headings': {
                'en': 'new dress'
            },
            'included_segments': ['admins'],
        }
        const httpOptions2 = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            })
        };
        this.httpClient.post('https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications', post_data, httpOptions2);

        this.router.navigate(['/list']);
    }
```

I've added the post after showing a notification(alert) for the user that the operation is completed.

And it is not being sent, even with no response at all!

Comment: Where in your application are you subscribing to the post?

Comment: after showing an alert for a user, and then I call this function `presentAlertMultipleButtons` when users submit the needed data. check question after update

Comment: If you never run [`subscribe`](https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing) on the post call, it will never run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @R.Richards comment.

I changed 
`this.httpClient.post('https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications', post_data, httpOptions2);`
 
to

```
this.httpClient.post('https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications', post_data, httpOptions2)
                        .subscribe(new_data => {
                            console.log(new_data)
                        }, error => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
```

and it works now